# How can I pass props to two components at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the render part of my location component. Once I get the this.state.location, then I can render Map.js

```
export default class Locatione extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  ...

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    try {

...
 render() {
    if (this.state.location !== null) {
      return <Map location={this.state.location} />;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I also access the props from History.js without having to render this component immediately as I do with Map.js?

Update:

There is nothing especial about History.js. It's just a simple component.

```
export default class History extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false
    };
  }
```

History.js is a component/page that you can access using React Navigation

```
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile
  },

  Main: {
    screen: Locatione
  },
  History: {
    screen: History,
    headerTitle: "aaa"
  }
});
```

Comment: Please paste History.js snippet. Also, where is History component suppose to sit?

Comment: Just did! @MantasGiniūnas